# Table padding make impacts border of the table (please see the border)

Tags: vba, ms-word

I apply table padding **(left,top,right,bottom)**. It impacts the border of the table in Word 2013 VBA.

1. first set border color for table
2. second set padding for table

[image]

**my code**

```
Dim tblBorder As Border

For Each tblBorder In table.Borders
tblBorder.Color = BorderColor
Next tblBorder

  With table
        .TopPadding = CentimetersToPoints(0.1)
        .BottomPadding = CentimetersToPoints(0.1)
        .LeftPadding = CentimetersToPoints(0.1)
        .RightPadding = CentimetersToPoints(0.1)
    End With
```

Comment: It's not clear what effect is problematic? Could you please be more specific about what changes when you run this code? Also, which version of Word is involved? You can use the [edit] link below your question to add more detail.

Comment: Try switching your code sequence. First apply padding and then set the border color. Does that make a difference?